# Adding data to Core Data if there is no data on device and no data in iCloud

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, xcode15

For an app I'm building I want to setup the app for the user when opening the app for the first time. This means creating a list (ListEntity) in Core Data. I do this in the persistence controller. (I use the auto generated controller by Xcode).

The app uses iCloud to sync data, in this case lists between devices. So when the user opens the app for the first time it needs to check if there is data in iCloud. If there is data in iCloud it shouldn't create a list in Core Data. But if there isn't then needs to create one.

```
@FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \ListEntity.name, ascending: true)],
animation: .default) 
var lists: FetchedResults<ListEntity>
```

I thought to be smart and just use a @FetchRequest at the end of the init in the PersistenceController and use a count on it. But this is a bad idea. Yes it work to count the items, but also gives an error. `Accessing StateObject's object without being installed on a View. This will create a new instance each time.` Also if I use the code below it does only work when there is no iCloud data and on device, but does work when there is data in iCloud. What results in two lists. What shouldn't be the case.

```
if lists.count != 0 {
    prepopulateData()
} else {
     UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "DataPreloaded")
}
```

The question is how to solve this in a way that it works and is clean code?

Comment: NSFetchRequest SwiftUI wrappers only work at strict/View level

Comment: That's what I found out aswel, but I thought it was needed to show what I already tried.